# Load more tiles in small div

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I am trying to achieve what foursquare did with their UI!
Offset center of map to the left https://foursquare.com/.
I have discovered how they did one part but can't implement the second part.
The first part was to load the map inside a small div (the one that will contain the markers), then with an `overflow:visible`, other tiles would fill the parent div which has `width:100%`.
The problem I am encountering right now is that only few tiles are showed when I do the overflow:visible.
My question is: how can I load more tiles inside of small div ?
The following picture explains how the tiles don't fill the whole container
[image]
Thank you.

**EDIT**

This is the full map shown on foursquare's main page it's called the map of tips.
 [image]
**BUT** this map is shown only because the container has an `overflow:visible`.
if the overflow was hidden, you would have : 
[image]

because the div size is only 600px.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very cool tutorial/article about the topic on A List Apart by Young Hahn from Mapbox which you can read here: http://alistapart.com/article/hack-your-maps You can see the end result here: https://www.mapbox.com/tutorial-sherlock/ He's using Mapbox but that's almost the same as using Leaflet (Mapbox is an extension of Leaflet) so everything done there works on Leaflet too. It uses a wrapper around the map element and relative and absolute positioning:

```
#pane {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:66.6666%;
}
#map  {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:200%;
    left:-50%;
}
```

Here's a little testcase using Leaflet on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vkTvRi?p=preview

Comment: Hi ! I'm actually not asking about adding a layer over the map.
I'm wondering how you can load a full width map inside a small div.
What blocks me is, the map loads only few tiles (the size of div)
Foursquare made it load the full width map, inside that small div.
Can you help ?

Comment: Could you supply a screenshot from FourSquare on what you mean because all i see is a normal map pane.